# Why do PCB designers opt for serpentine tuning and switchback tuning over spiral patterns when addressing length matching in their designs?

Tags: pcb, eda, length-matching, tuning

I am currently researching the length matching problem in the PCB EDA domain and am curious as to why tools such as Allegro and Altium primarily use accordion, trombone, and sawtooth patterns to address these issues. Are there any particular reasons for not considering spiral patterns or other alternative patterns in this context?

Comment: Because they have a line-like topology, making them more intuitive. IMO

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

May I ask if PCB layout designers would prefer an automatic router capable of solving the length matching problem without any topological constraints, such as intricate in-and-out routing or using commonly employed patterns like accordion, trombone, and sawtooth?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use autorouting. But I guess an autorouter wouldn't need to be constrained to such periodic patterns at all..It could just push/jam more track length  into any void along the way..

Comment: The problem with freeform length matching could be the number of degrees of freedom. With AI based routing, I guess this could be overcome and used eventually.

Comment: Because a spiral is an inductor.

Comment: @Mattman944 So is an accordion, trombone, etc., given a certain combination of system and characteristic impedances.

Comment: Two reasons dictate against spirals : (1) they can't be realised in 2 dimensions (you need another layer to access the inner connection; why add vias you don't need?) and (2) inductance is proportional to turns^2 which you usually don't want on matched traces.

Comment: @user_1818839 Thanks for your response! I'm curious as to why an additional layer is necessary to access the inner connection when using a spiral pattern in PCB design ?

Comment: Draw it out on paper! Get the inner contact to the outside without crossing any of the turns...

Comment: There was a period of time (about 30 years ago) when autorouters were used heavily. 
 Now, PCB signaling is pretty high speed, and unforgiving.  It is possible to get an autorouter to do what you want - if you constrain them heavily.  This makes them run really slow.  And, you have to spend a lot of time converting your wishes into constraints.  IMHO, that time is better spent just doing the layout yourself, by hand.  This is especially true for RF design.  I haven't used an autorouter in 20+ years.

Answer (score 1):

A spiral pattern would require a via in the center or if you didn't have a via in the center in the track stayed on the same layer then the pattern would probably have to be made very tight. Another thing is that a spiral would look like a trombone anyway.

Regardless a spiral pattern would have much more capacitance between traces of the same signal and a lot more inductance. Both of these things would create problems for high-speed signals over say somewhere around 500 MHz. Self capacitance between the same signal makes the signal arrive earlier versus the clock and inductance slows it down so a spiral would be a problem.

You can watch this video to see some of the the effects of capacitance and inductance of trombones which would relate to spirals:.

[Which length matching is the best? You may be surprised … | Eric Bogatin
YouTube · Robert Feranec](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dp6vx34jhTtI&ved=2ahUKEwjds_GEo9T-AhX2HUQIHdnJDe4QwqsBegQIERAB&usg=AOvVaw19TNyRBQ8VHlu1N5AqCEwU)
Jun 30, 2022